# Solving $z^2+\frac{9z^2}{(3+z)^2}=-5$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

Solve the equation 
$$z^2+\frac{9z^2}{(3+z)^2}=-5$$

PS.: The expanded form of a 4 degree polynomial is $$z^4+6z^3+23z^2+30z+45=0$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to
$$
z^4 + 6z^3 + 23z^2 + 30z + 45=(z^2 + 5z + 15)(z^2 + z + 3)=0
$$
for all $z\neq -3$. We can solve the quadratic equations, and hence also the degree $4$ equation. There are no real solutions. Of course, this is already clear, since
$$
z^2+a^2=-5
$$
is impossible over the real numbers.

Comment: Thanks! But how did you factored?

Comment: Just by multiplying out $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ and comparing coefficients. This goes fast and easy. If you only consider real solutions, we don't have to factorize at all.

Answer (score 2):

We have 
$$z^2-\frac{6z^2}{3+z}+\frac{9z^2}{(3+z)^2}+\frac{6z^2}{3+z}+5=0$$ or
$$\left(z-\frac{3z}{3+z}\right)^2+\frac{6z^2}{3+z}+5=0$$ or
$$\left(\frac{z^2}{3+z}\right)^2+\frac{6z^2}{3+z}+5=0$$ or
$$\left(\frac{z^2}{3+z}+1\right)\left(\frac{z^2}{3+z}+5\right)=0.$$
Can you end it now?